# Symmetry for finite cyclic groups (Z/pZ)∗

Tags: group-theory

How well is it known that for $i$ such that $1 \leq i \leq \frac{p − 1}2$:

$$
g^{i+(p−1)/2} = g^{i−1+(p−1)/2} − g^i + g^{i−1} \pmod p
$$

Whilst working in the finite cyclic group of prime moduli $(Z/pZ)^*$, given g to be a primitive root of p.

Comment: Let $p=7$, $g=2$, and $i=1$. The LHS is $2^{1+3}\equiv2$ and the RHS is $2^{0+3}-2^1+2^0\equiv1-2+1\equiv-2$. Your equation does not hold.

Comment: i forgot to add for g to be a primitive root of p. sorry. so 2 is not a primitive root of 7

Comment: Isn't it a direct consequence of $g^{(p−1)/2}\equiv−1\bmod p$ ?

Comment: @lhf possibly. But I still found it kind of intriguing that the "second part" of a finite cyclic group is the "mirror: of the "first part" under certain circumstances . I wonder if this property is used anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g$ is a primitive root of $p$, then 
$
g^{(p−1)/2}\equiv-1\bmod p
$. Hence
$$
g^{i+(p−1)/2} \equiv g^i g^{(p−1)/2} \equiv -g^i\bmod p
$$
and
$$
g^{i−1+(p−1)/2} − g^i + g^{i−1} \equiv g^{i−1} g^{(p−1)/2} − g^i + g^{i−1} \equiv -g^{i−1} − g^i + g^{i−1} \equiv -g^i \bmod p
$$

Comment: do you know any application of this formula?